# How can I add a message box in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to display messages like "user is authenticated" or "account created" in Shiny with `uiOutput`, but it overrides the front page of my Shiny dashboard which is not required.

Is there a function in Shiny in which we can add a message box like thing, which can be closed once the message is displayed and then the user can proceed?

Comment: yes, you can use `insertUI` and `removeUI`, but base shiny does not have "message box" as UIs, you'll have to customize it with some css.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [`modalDialogs`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html) for that, here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("login", "Log in"),
  textInput('userid','User id:',value=' definitely not Florian')
)
server = function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "You have logged in.",
      paste0("It seems you have logged in as",input$userid,'.'),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!!actually i did used modaldialog for user login but did not thought of using it for displaying message.It works.